# How to identify stepper motors?

Tags: motor, stepper-motor

I have a bunch of motors that I collected from different places. How can I figure out which ones are stepper motors? I have access to the datasheet for most of them, just not sure what to look for.

Links to two pdf datasheets [motor 1](http://mech.vub.ac.be/teaching/info/mechatronica/finished_projects_2007/Groep%202/Afbeelding/motor_datasheet_MABUCHIrf500tb.pdf), and [motor 2](http://www.tedss.com/DataSheets/2099/2099000348.pdf)

[image]

Comment: It might be worth including a link to a datasheet or two you're confused about. Normally the main challenge with motors from unidentified sources is finding the datasheet in the first place.

Comment: The number of wires coming out can definitively separate the regular motors from the stepper motors (the latter having more than 2 wires). If you have the datasheets, you have the part numbers; you clearly have access to the Internet - should be a simple search after that.

Comment: @RonJ BLDC motors, a bunch of servo motors, and miscellaneous other odd and exotic motors have more than 2 leads, yet are not stepper motors.

Comment: Upload an image of some of the motors

Comment: @PeterJ I added links for two.

Comment: You only have two stepper motors there. Upper right three motors are brushed DC motors. Bottom two motors (with the black plastic things on them) are *probably* AC brushless motors. The only motors that are likely steppers are the two with the leadscrews in the upper-left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the motor has four or more winding connections, then it is likely a stepper.

If it has four wires, it's a bipolar only stepper. If it has five wires, it's a unipolar only stepper. If it has six or eight wires, it can be used as either.

Another way to find out is to open each motor. If the rotor has a number of ridges at some consistent separation angle, and there are no brushes, then you're likely looking at a stepper motor. (Brushless motors also have no brushes, but don't have the telltale "ridged" stators AFAIK.)

Comment: You **should not** open high performance stepper motors, as removing the rotor without inserting a keeper can lead to weaking some types of magnets.  It's also easy in a shop environment to contaminate the magnet gaps with bits of metal.

Comment: Yes -- "dont break it" is a good caveat :-) You can inspect the rotor without removing it, typically. If you can't afford to lose the motor and haven't worked with the type before, then even opening it might be risky.

Comment: Check the wires with an ohm-meter. If you have two pairs of non-connected wires, it's a bipolar stepper. I had a floppy center-motor with four wires, where the forth seems to be the center of a star topology. Probably a brushless DC... at least from what I'm reading, center motors of floppy/cdrom/dvd are usually not steppers.